# miscutils error when compiling BusyBox for Android

Tags: command-line, make, android, busybox

I'm trying to compile Busybox for Android.
Command used:

```
make CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang \
     AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar \
     RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ranlib \
     CFLAGS="-I/home/umut/musl-cross-make/build/local/aarch64-linux-musl/obj_sysroot/include" \
     busybox
```

The error i get:  *make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:198: miscutils/time.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:744: miscutils] Error 2*

What is the error exactly and how can i fix?

Comment: There's really not enough error information to go on - are there not more lines before the `Error 1` message? If not, try re-running the command with the verbose flag set i.e. `make V=1`